# How to zero out all entries of a dask array less than the top k

Tags: numpy, dask

I want to zero out all of the elements of a dask.array except for the top few elements.  How do I do this?

#### Example

Say I have a small dask array like the following:

```
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da
x = np.array([0, 4, 2, 3, 1])
x = da.from_array(x, chunks=(2,))
```

How do I zero out all but the two largest elements?  I want something like the following:

```
>>> result.compute()
array([0, 4, 0, 3, 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a combination of the [topk](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.topk) function and inplace setitem

```
top = x.topk(2)
x[x < top[-1]] = 0

>>> x.compute()
array([0, 4, 0, 3, 0])
```

Note that this won't stream particularly nicely through memory.  If you're using the single machine scheduler then you might want to do this in two passes by explicitly computing `top` ahead of time:

```
top = x.topk(2)
top = top.compute()  # pass through data once to get top elements
x[x < top[-1]] = 0   # then pass through again applying filter

>>> x.compute()
array([0, 4, 0, 3, 0])
```

This only matters if you're trying to stream through a large dataset on a single machine and should not affect you much if you're on a distributed system.